# SpeechBrain: dataio_prepare function with csv

Tags: python, pytorch, speech-recognition, pytorch-dataloader

I am currently following the ASRfromScratch tutorial but I am trying to make it work with the Fluent Speech Dataset https://fluent.ai/fluent-speech-commands-a-dataset-for-spoken-language-understanding-research/. I was able to go through the Tokenizer section and the Language Model section with no problem but I am struggling with the SpeechRecognizer section. I modified the dataio_prepare function as such, but I am not sure if it is the correct approach:

```
    """This function prepares the datasets to be used in the brain class.
    It also defines the data processing pipeline through user-defined functions.


    Arguments
    ---------
    hparams : dict
        This dictionary is loaded from the `train.yaml` file, and it includes
        all the hyperparameters needed for dataset construction and loading.

    Returns
    -------
    datasets : dict
        Dictionary containing "train", "valid", and "test" keys that correspond
        to the DynamicItemDataset objects.
    """
    # Define audio pipeline. In this case, we simply read the path contained
    # in the variable wav with the audio reader.
    @sb.utils.data_pipeline.takes("path")
    @sb.utils.data_pipeline.provides("sig")
    def audio_pipeline(path):
        """Load the audio signal. This is done on the CPU in the `collate_fn`."""
        sig = sb.dataio.dataio.read_audio('../fluent_speech_commands_dataset/' + path)
        return sig

    # Define text processing pipeline. We start from the raw text and then
    # encode it using the tokenizer. The tokens with BOS are used for feeding
    # decoder during training, the tokens with EOS for computing the cost function.
    # The tokens without BOS or EOS is for computing CTC loss.
    @sb.utils.data_pipeline.takes("transcription")
    @sb.utils.data_pipeline.provides(
        "words", "tokens_list", "tokens_bos", "tokens_eos", "tokens"
    )
    def text_pipeline(transcription):
        """Processes the transcriptions to generate proper labels"""
        yield transcription
        tokens_list = hparams["tokenizer"].encode_as_ids(transcription)
        yield tokens_list
        tokens_bos = torch.LongTensor([hparams["bos_index"]] + (tokens_list))
        yield tokens_bos
        tokens_eos = torch.LongTensor(tokens_list + [hparams["eos_index"]])
        yield tokens_eos
        tokens = torch.LongTensor(tokens_list)
        yield tokens

    # Define datasets from json data manifest file
    # Define datasets sorted by ascending lengths for efficiency
    datasets = {}
    data_folder = hparams["data_folder"]
    for dataset in ["train", "valid", "test"]:
        datasets[dataset] = sb.dataio.dataset.DynamicItemDataset.from_csv(
            csv_path = hparams[f"{dataset}_annotation"],
            replacements={"data_root": data_folder},
            dynamic_items=[audio_pipeline, text_pipeline],
            output_keys=[
                "id",
                "sig",
                "words",
                "tokens_bos",
                "tokens_eos",
                "tokens",
            ],
            )
        hparams[f"{dataset}_dataloader_opts"]["shuffle"] = False

    # Sorting training data with ascending order makes the code  much
    # faster  because we minimize zero-padding. In most of the cases, this
    # does not harm the performance.
    if hparams["sorting"] == "ascending":
        datasets["train"] = datasets["train"].filtered_sorted(sort_key="length")
        hparams["train_dataloader_opts"]["shuffle"] = False

    elif hparams["sorting"] == "descending":
        datasets["train"] = datasets["train"].filtered_sorted(
            sort_key="length", reverse=True
        )
        hparams["train_dataloader_opts"]["shuffle"] = False

    elif hparams["sorting"] == "random":
        hparams["train_dataloader_opts"]["shuffle"] = True
        pass

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "sorting must be random, ascending or descending"
        )
    return datasets
```

To clarify, the .csv files look like that :

```
ID,path,speakerId,transcription,action,object,location
0,wavs/speakers/2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb/0a3129c0-4474-11e9-a9a5-5dbec3b8816a.wav,2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb,Change language,change language,none,none
1,wavs/speakers/2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb/0ee42a80-4474-11e9-a9a5-5dbec3b8816a.wav,2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb,Resume,activate,music,none
2,wavs/speakers/2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb/144d5be0-4474-11e9-a9a5-5dbec3b8816a.wav,2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb,Turn the lights on,activate,lights,none
3,wavs/speakers/2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb/1811b6e0-4474-11e9-a9a5-5dbec3b8816a.wav,2BqVo8kVB2Skwgyb,Switch on the lights,activate,lights,none
```

Also I removed the lines corresponding to the prenaining phase because I don't know how to make them work with my own dataset.

```
run_on_main(hparams["pretrainer"].collect_files)
hparams["pretrainer"].load_collected(device=run_opts["device"])
```

My problem is that the fit model phase keeps getting stuck at the first data to process and I don't know how to fix it :

```
(Polette) aurelienmarchal@aurelienmarchal-X556UQ:~/Stage/Polette/speech_recognizer$ python3 train.py train.yaml --batch_size=2
../noise/rirs_noises.zip exists. Skipping download
speechbrain.core - Beginning experiment!
speechbrain.core - Experiment folder: results/CRDNN_BPE_960h_LM/42
speechbrain.core - Info: ckpt_interval_minutes arg from hparam file is used
speechbrain.core - 171.8M trainable parameters in ASR
speechbrain.utils.checkpoints - Would load a checkpoint here, but none found yet.
speechbrain.utils.epoch_loop - Going into epoch 1
  0%|                                                                                                  | 0/11566 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
speechbrain.core - Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 452, in <module>
    asr_brain.fit(
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speechbrain/core.py", line 1011, in fit
    for batch in t:
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1133, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 517, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 557, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speechbrain/dataio/batch.py", line 125, in __init__
    padded = PaddedData(*padding_func(values, **padding_kwargs))
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speechbrain/utils/data_utils.py", line 415, in batch_pad_right
    padded, valid_percent = pad_right_to(
  File "/home/aurelienmarchal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/speechbrain/utils/data_utils.py", line 353, in pad_right_to
    valid_vals.append(tensor.shape[j] / target_shape[j])
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Also, my train.yaml looks like that :

```
# ############################################################################
# Model: E2E ASR with attention-based ASR
# Encoder: CRDNN
# Decoder: GRU + beamsearch + RNNLM
# Tokens: 500 BPE
# losses: CTC+ NLL
# Training: mini-librispeech
# Pre-Training: librispeech 960h
# Authors:  Ju-Chieh Chou, Mirco Ravanelli, Abdel Heba, Peter Plantinga, Samuele Cornell 2020
# # ############################################################################

# Seed needs to be set at top of yaml, before objects with parameters are instantiated
seed: 42
__set_seed: !apply:torch.manual_seed [!ref <seed>]

# If you plan to train a system on an HPC cluster with a big dataset,
# we strongly suggest doing the following:
# 1- Compress the dataset in a single tar or zip file.
# 2- Copy your dataset locally (i.e., the local disk of the computing node).
# 3- Uncompress the dataset in the local folder.
# 4- Set data_folder with the local path
# Reading data from the local disk of the compute node (e.g. $SLURM_TMPDIR with SLURM-based clusters) is very important.
# It allows you to read the data much faster without slowing down the shared filesystem.

data_folder: ../fluent_speech_commands_dataset # In this case, data will be automatically downloaded here.
data_folder_rirs: ../noise # noise/ris dataset will automatically be downloaded here
output_folder: !ref results/CRDNN_BPE_960h_LM/<seed>
wer_file: !ref <output_folder>/wer.txt
save_folder: !ref <output_folder>/save
train_log: !ref <output_folder>/train_log.txt

# Language model (LM) pretraining
# NB: To avoid mismatch, the speech recognizer must be trained with the same
# tokenizer used for LM training. Here, we download everything from the
# speechbrain HuggingFace repository. However, a local path pointing to a
# directory containing the lm.ckpt and tokenizer.ckpt may also be specified
# instead. E.g if you want to use your own LM / tokenizer.
pretrained_path: ../language_model/results/RNNLM/save/CKPT+2021-05-12+15-27-08+00/


# Path where data manifest files will be stored. The data manifest files are created by the
# data preparation script
train_annotation: ../fluent_speech_commands_dataset/data/train_data.csv
valid_annotation: ../fluent_speech_commands_dataset/data/valid_data.csv
test_annotation: ../fluent_speech_commands_dataset/data/test_data.csv

# The train logger writes training statistics to a file, as well as stdout.
train_logger: !new:speechbrain.utils.train_logger.FileTrainLogger
    save_file: !ref <train_log>

# Training parameters
number_of_epochs: 15
number_of_ctc_epochs: 5
batch_size: 8
lr: 1.0
ctc_weight: 0.5
sorting: random
ckpt_interval_minutes: 15 # save checkpoint every N min
label_smoothing: 0.1

# Dataloader options
train_dataloader_opts:
    batch_size: !ref <batch_size>

valid_dataloader_opts:
    batch_size: !ref <batch_size>

test_dataloader_opts:
    batch_size: !ref <batch_size>


# Feature parameters
sample_rate: 16000
n_fft: 400
n_mels: 40

# Model parameters
activation: !name:torch.nn.LeakyReLU
dropout: 0.15
cnn_blocks: 2
cnn_channels: (128, 256)
inter_layer_pooling_size: (2, 2)
cnn_kernelsize: (3, 3)
time_pooling_size: 4
rnn_class: !name:speechbrain.nnet.RNN.LSTM
rnn_layers: 4
rnn_neurons: 1024
rnn_bidirectional: True
dnn_blocks: 2
dnn_neurons: 512
emb_size: 128
dec_neurons: 1024
output_neurons: 500  # Number of tokens (same as LM)
blank_index: 0
bos_index: 0
eos_index: 0
unk_index: 0

# Decoding parameters
min_decode_ratio: 0.0
max_decode_ratio: 1.0
valid_beam_size: 8
test_beam_size: 80
eos_threshold: 1.5
using_max_attn_shift: True
max_attn_shift: 240
lm_weight: 0.50
ctc_weight_decode: 0.0
coverage_penalty: 1.5
temperature: 1.25
temperature_lm: 1.25

# The first object passed to the Brain class is this "Epoch Counter"
# which is saved by the Checkpointer so that training can be resumed
# if it gets interrupted at any point.
epoch_counter: !new:speechbrain.utils.epoch_loop.EpochCounter
    limit: !ref <number_of_epochs>

# Feature extraction
compute_features: !new:speechbrain.lobes.features.Fbank
    sample_rate: !ref <sample_rate>
    n_fft: !ref <n_fft>
    n_mels: !ref <n_mels>

# Feature normalization (mean and std)
normalize: !new:speechbrain.processing.features.InputNormalization
    norm_type: global

# Added noise and reverb come from OpenRIR dataset, automatically
# downloaded and prepared with this Environmental Corruption class.
env_corrupt: !new:speechbrain.lobes.augment.EnvCorrupt
    openrir_folder: !ref <data_folder_rirs>
    babble_prob: 0.0
    reverb_prob: 0.0
    noise_prob: 1.0
    noise_snr_low: 0
    noise_snr_high: 15

# Adds speech change + time and frequency dropouts (time-domain implementation).
augmentation: !new:speechbrain.lobes.augment.TimeDomainSpecAugment
    sample_rate: !ref <sample_rate>
    speeds: [95, 100, 105]

# The CRDNN model is an encoder that combines CNNs, RNNs, and DNNs.
encoder: !new:speechbrain.lobes.models.CRDNN.CRDNN
    input_shape: [null, null, !ref <n_mels>]
    activation: !ref <activation>
    dropout: !ref <dropout>
    cnn_blocks: !ref <cnn_blocks>
    cnn_channels: !ref <cnn_channels>
    cnn_kernelsize: !ref <cnn_kernelsize>
    inter_layer_pooling_size: !ref <inter_layer_pooling_size>
    time_pooling: True
    using_2d_pooling: False
    time_pooling_size: !ref <time_pooling_size>
    rnn_class: !ref <rnn_class>
    rnn_layers: !ref <rnn_layers>
    rnn_neurons: !ref <rnn_neurons>
    rnn_bidirectional: !ref <rnn_bidirectional>
    rnn_re_init: True
    dnn_blocks: !ref <dnn_blocks>
    dnn_neurons: !ref <dnn_neurons>
    use_rnnp: False

# Embedding (from indexes to an embedding space of dimension emb_size).
embedding: !new:speechbrain.nnet.embedding.Embedding
    num_embeddings: !ref <output_neurons>
    embedding_dim: !ref <emb_size>

# Attention-based RNN decoder.
decoder: !new:speechbrain.nnet.RNN.AttentionalRNNDecoder
    enc_dim: !ref <dnn_neurons>
    input_size: !ref <emb_size>
    rnn_type: gru
    attn_type: location
    hidden_size: !ref <dec_neurons>
    attn_dim: 1024
    num_layers: 1
    scaling: 1.0
    channels: 10
    kernel_size: 100
    re_init: True
    dropout: !ref <dropout>

# Linear transformation on the top of the encoder.
ctc_lin: !new:speechbrain.nnet.linear.Linear
    input_size: !ref <dnn_neurons>
    n_neurons: !ref <output_neurons>

# Linear transformation on the top of the decoder.
seq_lin: !new:speechbrain.nnet.linear.Linear
    input_size: !ref <dec_neurons>
    n_neurons: !ref <output_neurons>

# Final softmax (for log posteriors computation).
log_softmax: !new:speechbrain.nnet.activations.Softmax
    apply_log: True

# Cost definition for the CTC part.
ctc_cost: !name:speechbrain.nnet.losses.ctc_loss
    blank_index: !ref <blank_index>


# Tokenizer initialization
tokenizer: !new:sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor

# Objects in "modules" dict will have their parameters moved to the correct
# device, as well as having train()/eval() called on them by the Brain class
modules:
    encoder: !ref <encoder>
    embedding: !ref <embedding>
    decoder: !ref <decoder>
    ctc_lin: !ref <ctc_lin>
    seq_lin: !ref <seq_lin>
    normalize: !ref <normalize>
    env_corrupt: !ref <env_corrupt>
    lm_model: !ref <lm_model>

# Gathering all the submodels in a single model object.
model: !new:torch.nn.ModuleList
    - - !ref <encoder>
      - !ref <embedding>
      - !ref <decoder>
      - !ref <ctc_lin>
      - !ref <seq_lin>

# This is the RNNLM that is used according to the Huggingface repository
# NB: It has to match the pre-trained RNNLM!!
lm_model: !new:speechbrain.lobes.models.RNNLM.RNNLM
    output_neurons: !ref <output_neurons>
    embedding_dim: !ref <emb_size>
    activation: !name:torch.nn.LeakyReLU
    dropout: 0.0
    rnn_layers: 2
    rnn_neurons: 2048
    dnn_blocks: 1
    dnn_neurons: 512
    return_hidden: True  # For inference

# Beamsearch is applied on the top of the decoder. If the language model is
# given, a language model is applied (with a weight specified in lm_weight).
# If ctc_weight is set, the decoder uses CTC + attention beamsearch. This
# improves the performance, but slows down decoding. For a description of
# the other parameters, please see the speechbrain.decoders.S2SRNNBeamSearchLM.

# It makes sense to have a lighter search during validation. In this case,
# we don't use the LM and CTC probabilities during decoding.
valid_search: !new:speechbrain.decoders.S2SRNNBeamSearcher
    embedding: !ref <embedding>
    decoder: !ref <decoder>
    linear: !ref <seq_lin>
    ctc_linear: !ref <ctc_lin>
    bos_index: !ref <bos_index>
    eos_index: !ref <eos_index>
    blank_index: !ref <blank_index>
    min_decode_ratio: !ref <min_decode_ratio>
    max_decode_ratio: !ref <max_decode_ratio>
    beam_size: !ref <valid_beam_size>
    eos_threshold: !ref <eos_threshold>
    using_max_attn_shift: !ref <using_max_attn_shift>
    max_attn_shift: !ref <max_attn_shift>
    coverage_penalty: !ref <coverage_penalty>
    temperature: !ref <temperature>

# The final decoding on the test set can be more computationally demanding.
# In this case, we use the LM + CTC probabilities during decoding as well.
# Please, remove this part if you need a faster decoder.
test_search: !new:speechbrain.decoders.S2SRNNBeamSearchLM
    embedding: !ref <embedding>
    decoder: !ref <decoder>
    linear: !ref <seq_lin>
    ctc_linear: !ref <ctc_lin>
    language_model: !ref <lm_model>
    bos_index: !ref <bos_index>
    eos_index: !ref <eos_index>
    blank_index: !ref <blank_index>
    min_decode_ratio: !ref <min_decode_ratio>
    max_decode_ratio: !ref <max_decode_ratio>
    beam_size: !ref <test_beam_size>
    eos_threshold: !ref <eos_threshold>
    using_max_attn_shift: !ref <using_max_attn_shift>
    max_attn_shift: !ref <max_attn_shift>
    coverage_penalty: !ref <coverage_penalty>
    lm_weight: !ref <lm_weight>
    ctc_weight: !ref <ctc_weight_decode>
    temperature: !ref <temperature>
    temperature_lm: !ref <temperature_lm>

# This function manages learning rate annealing over the epochs.
# We here use the NewBoB algorithm, that anneals the learning rate if
# the improvements over two consecutive epochs is less than the defined
# threshold.
lr_annealing: !new:speechbrain.nnet.schedulers.NewBobScheduler
    initial_value: !ref <lr>
    improvement_threshold: 0.0025
    annealing_factor: 0.8
    patient: 0

# This optimizer will be constructed by the Brain class after all parameters
# are moved to the correct device. Then it will be added to the checkpointer.
opt_class: !name:torch.optim.Adadelta
    lr: !ref <lr>
    rho: 0.95
    eps: 1.e-8

# Functions that compute the statistics to track during the validation step.
error_rate_computer: !name:speechbrain.utils.metric_stats.ErrorRateStats

cer_computer: !name:speechbrain.utils.metric_stats.ErrorRateStats
    split_tokens: True

# This object is used for saving the state of training both so that it
# can be resumed if it gets interrupted, and also so that the best checkpoint
# can be later loaded for evaluation or inference.
checkpointer: !new:speechbrain.utils.checkpoints.Checkpointer
    checkpoints_dir: !ref <save_folder>
    recoverables:
        model: !ref <model>
        scheduler: !ref <lr_annealing>
        normalizer: !ref <normalize>
        counter: !ref <epoch_counter>

# This object is used to pretrain the language model and the tokenizers
# (defined above). In this case, we also pretrain the ASR model (to make
# sure the model converges on a small amount of data)
#pretrainer: !new:speechbrain.utils.parameter_transfer.Pretrainer
#    collect_in: !ref <save_folder>
#    loadables:
#        lm: !ref <lm_model>
#        tokenizer: !ref <tokenizer>
#        model: !ref <model>
#    paths:
#        lm: !ref <pretrained_path>/lm.ckpt
#        tokenizer: !ref <pretrained_path>/tokenizer.ckpt
#        model: !ref <pretrained_path>/asr.ckpt
```

That's it ! If you have an idea on how to do it or if you are comfortable with the SpeechBrain library let my now !
Thank you for reading my post

Comment: Could you solve this? I am also getting this error suddenly! The model ran fine last time also!!

Answer (score 0):

It's already about two months since you posted this problem. Maybe you have already solved it. I was also facing the same problem. So I thought to post how I solved the problem as it may become helpful to others.

I was trying to train the model with the LibriSpeech Bengali dataset. In my case, the problem was with the tokenizer. In the `text_pipeline` we are calling the tokenizer from the YAML file in this line: `tokens_list = hparams["tokenizer"].encode_as_ids(transcription)`. We also call it during decoding. Now if you look at the YAML file. You'll find the tokenizer to be: `sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor`. So, this is not using the `.model` file created during training the tokenizer. As a result, it creates empty lists while tokenizing. Thus `target_shape[j]` to be `0` and causing the `ZeroDivisionError`. So, I modified the `text_pipeline` as follows:

```
import sentencepiece

def text_pipeline(words):
    yield words
    tokenizer = sentencepiece.SentencePieceProcessor(model_file=hparams['tokenizer_model'])
    tokens_list = tokenizer.encode_as_ids(words)
    yield tokens_list
    tokens_bos = torch.LongTensor([hparams["bos_index"]] + (tokens_list))
    yield tokens_bos
    tokens_eos = torch.LongTensor(tokens_list + [hparams["eos_index"]])
    yield tokens_eos
    tokens = torch.LongTensor(tokens_list)
    yield tokens
```

And In the YAML file, I pointed the path to `.model` file in the `tokenizer_model` field as follows:

```
tokenizer_model: path/to/1000_unigram.model
```

You may need to change the tokenizer during the decoding phase in the `compute_objectives` function as well. Also you need to keep the following lines:

```
run_on_main(hparams["pretrainer"].collect_files)
hparams["pretrainer"].load_collected(device=run_opts["device"])
```

These lines will create a symbolic link to your Language model's `.ckpt` file. But you do not need to load the pre-trained models for ASR and tokenizer. So change the following block:

```
pretrainer: !new:speechbrain.utils.parameter_transfer.Pretrainer
    collect_in: !ref <save_folder>
    loadables:
        lm: !ref <lm_model>
        tokenizer: !ref <tokenizer>
        model: !ref <model>
    paths:
        lm: !ref <pretrained_path>/lm.ckpt
        tokenizer: !ref <pretrained_path>/tokenizer.ckpt
        model: !ref <pretrained_path>/asr.ckpt
```

to:

```
pretrainer: !new:speechbrain.utils.parameter_transfer.Pretrainer
    collect_in: !ref <save_folder>
    loadables:
        lm: !ref <lm_model>
    paths:
        lm: path/to/language/model.ckpt
```

However, if you want to use the pre-trained ASR model and/or tokenizer, you can change this block accordingly.

I hope this may help you if you already did not solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I posted this issue on the Speechbrain and this was their answer, written by [TParcollet](https://github.com/TParcollet): [github answer](https://github.com/speechbrain/speechbrain/issues/753#event-4848209165):

> Hi, you obtain this error because some of your data are stereo (or more) which is not managed by the padding in this way. You will need to add the following to the audio_pipeline:
>
> ```
> info = torchaudio.info(wav)
> sig = sb.dataio.dataio.read_audio(wav)
> if info.num_channels > 1:
>    sig = torch.mean(sig, dim=1)
> ```
>
> Something like that. You also need to make the pretrainer work if you have a pretrained LM and Tokenizer, otherwise they won't be loaded ;)

I didn't have a chance to test it but there you go.